# Restful webservice which returns xml

Tags: jquery, xml, json, rest

I'm accessing a restful webservice which returns xml. the problem is i don't know what to do since i'm just starting to dive into restful web services. all i know is that it doesn't work especially if the dataType you are using is json or jsonp. But also the service is cross-browser so i think it must be in jsonp format. thank you

Comment: and your question is what exactly?

Comment: how can i parse or somehow make it work when my restful web service returns xml and i want it jsonp since i am expecting it jsonp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at [Content-Type](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.17) and [Accept](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1) header values

The concept is called [content negotiation.](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec12.html) .